# Teamcity fails to identify all tests in gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, teamcity, robolectric

We currently have 460+ tests on more than one `gradle` project (we run a build that runs tests from all projects at once).
we're also using `robolectric` 3.0 and using a custom runner (just overriding `getAppManifest`)

I've just upgraded `robolectric` to 3.1.4 and since then `Teamcity` only reports about 160 / 460 tests.
what can go wrong here with our setup?
running the same `gradle` task locally seems to run all the expected tests.

we're using `Teamcity Enterprise 9.1.5 (build 37377)`

Thanks

Comment: Does Teamcity run test by itself? Or it is gradle?

Comment: hey , it's a gradle task